# Can I avoid round-trip to "get user for session" on SPA load?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

My SPA loads, then does an XHR to /currentuser route to check for a signed in user against the cookie/session sent along in the request. I don’t show the app (even though assets have loaded) until that round trip has completed and hasTriedLoadingUser is set.

Seems standard for SPA apps that don’t have server-side rendering (I’m using Polymer), right?

I’m thinking of doing the /currentuser check on server side with the initial request for the app, and then writing the user object as JSON to the returned file itself. Then I'd parse it client side (JSON.decode), thus avoiding a round-trip.

Your thoughts? How do you handle this in your SPA (where, like Polymer, server-side rendering is not supported)?

Comment: To avoid doing an additional ajax request in your SPA code, perhaps embed the user object on your server-rendered index.html, inside a `<script>` block.

Comment: Right, that's what I suggested in the q. Is that common/best practice?